# Zend render templates out of scripts folder

Tags: zend-framework

i have one problem... In my Zend project I made subfolders in views folder... So beside scripts I also have forms and templates. But when I try to render template in forms folder from some controller it automaticly looks in scripts folder and it set the scripts folder as base path... I found this function:
$this->view->setBasePath("../application/views/forms");
but problem is that it automaticly asume that there is a script subfolder in forms folder. But i dont want to create one because from my point of view is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `setBasePath()` does this: `Given a base path, sets the script, helper, and filter paths relative to it. Assumes a directory structure of: basePath/ scripts/ helpers/ filters/`

Try `setScriptPath()` instead.